# Tkinter: How do I use the value of a scale-widget to change the text of a label-widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement a simple difficulty-slider, so I created a scale-widget.

Using the slider, the user can select the difficulty-setting he wants to play on. I also want to have a label-widget that displays the chosen difficulty (Easy, Normal, Hard, usw...)

So the value of the scale-widget is used to continuously update the text of the label-widget. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to work as intended. I think something is wrong with the Adjust_scl-function. Could you help me out?

I'm quite new to Tk and Python in general.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Difficulty")
        

class Difficulty:

    def __init__ (self, master):
    
         global vel_1
         vel_1 = IntVar()

         self.dif_scale = Scale(master,variable = vel_1,from_ = 3,to = -3,resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=450,tickinterval=1, label="Your Dice Roll Modifier",showvalue=0,command=self.Adjust_scl)
         self.dif_scale.pack()

         self.dif_label = Label(master)
         self.dif_label.pack()

    
    def Adjust_scl(self,random_parameter):

        if vel_1 == 0:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Normal")
        elif vel_1 == -1:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Challenging")
        elif vel_1 == -2:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Hard")
        elif vel_1 == -3:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Insane")
        elif vel_1 == 1:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Easy")
        elif vel_1 == 2:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Walk in the Park")
        elif vel_1 == 3:
        self.dif_label.config(text="Storymode")



dif = Difficulty(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The Adjust_scl-function refuses to work without the random_parameter, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use get() to get the value from the scale, and you need to fix the indentation of your if/elifs.

```py
   def Adjust_scl(self,random_parameter):

        if vel_1.get() == 0:          
            self.dif_label.config(text="Normal")
        elif vel_1.get() == -1:
            self.dif_label.config(text="Challenging")
        elif vel_1.get() == -2:
            self.dif_label.config(text="Hard")
        elif vel_1.get() == -3:
            self.dif_label.config(text="Insane")
        elif vel_1.get() == 1:
            self.dif_label.config(text="Easy")
        elif vel_1.get() == 2:
            self.dif_label.config(text="Walk in the Park")
        elif vel_1.get() == 3:
            self.dif_label.config(text="Storymode")
```

You might also want to consider putting the text for the levels into a list.

If you did that you wouldn't need the long if/elif code.

Here's the code with a list for the levels, and using self.vel_1 so you don't need to use global.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Difficulty")
        
class Difficulty:

    def __init__ (self, master):
    
         self.vel_1 = IntVar()
         self.levels = ['Insane', 'Hard', 'Challenging', 'Normal', 'Easy', 'Walk in the Park', 'Story Mode']
         self.dif_scale = Scale(master,variable = self.vel_1,from_ = 3,to = -3,resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=450,tickinterval=1, label="Your Dice Roll Modifier",showvalue=0,command=self.Adjust_scl)
         self.dif_scale.pack()

         self.dif_label = Label(master)
         self.dif_label.pack()

    def Adjust_scl(self,random_parameter):

        level = self.vel_1.get()+3
        print(level)
        self.dif_label.config(text=self.levels[level])
        
dif = Difficulty(root)

root.mainloop()
```